# LINQ query with DateTime column, groupby Date only with 2nd variable, count total entries for each subgroup

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have a radiology database where reports are logged by date, time included, and with their author, as well as study type.

I want to generate a summary report counting total number of reports per author for the day, with subcounts of different study types.

So I am trying to run a query that groups by day date and by unique author ID, then counts total number of reports per author, and the different subcounts.

So far I have this:

```c#
List<DeNovoGraph> ac = new List<DeNovoGraph>();
TALKRIS2Entities db = new TALKRIS2Entities();

// gets list of reports for past 28 days

var minDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-28);
var query = from queryResult in db.report_compare
            join a in db.accessions on queryResult.report_id equals a.report_id
            join p in db.procedures on a.procedure_code equals p.procedure_code
            where queryResult.date_opened > minDate
            select new DeNovoGraph()
            {
                report_id = queryResult.report_id,
                author = queryResult.users,
                date_opened = queryResult.date_opened,
                description = p.description
            };
var attendings = query.ToList();


// separate userid's which are attendings vs residents from separate table (only want to count attendings)

var tuQuery = from uq in db.t_user.AsEnumerable()
              where uq.type.Contains("Attending") &&
              uq.active.Contains("Y")
              select new t_user()
              {
                  id = uq.id
              };
string[] tuArray = tuQuery.Select(x => x.id).ToArray();

foreach (string x in tuArray)
{
    foreach (var row in attendings)
    {
        if (row.author.Contains(x))
        {
            row.attending = x;
        }
    }
};

// convert study description into counts of study type

foreach (var row in attendings)
{
    if (row.author.Contains(","))
    {
        row.denovo = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        row.denovo = 1;
    };

    if (row.description.StartsWith("XR") || row.description.StartsWith("X-R"))
    {
        row.xr = 1;
    }
    else if (row.description.StartsWith("CT"))
    {
        row.ct = 1;
    }
    else if (row.description.StartsWith("US"))
    {
        row.us = 1;
    }
    else if (row.description.StartsWith("MR"))
    {
        row.mr = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        row.other = 1;
    };
}

foreach (var row in attendings)
{
    ac.Add(new DeNovoGraph()
    {
        report_id = row.report_id,
        author = row.author,
        attending = row.attending,
        date_opened = row.date_opened,
        description = row.description,
        denovo = row.denovo,
        ct = row.ct,
        xr = row.xr,
        us = row.us,
        mr = row.mr,
        other = row.other
    });
}

// do the grouping/math

var mathQuery = ac.GroupBy(u => new CountModel()
{
    tdate = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(u.date_opened),
    attending = u.attending

}).Select(y => new CountModel()
{
        tdate = y.Key.tdate,
        attending = y.Key.attending,
        total = y.Count()
        //denovo count for day
        //xr count for day, etc
}).ToList();
```

That last mathQuery part doesn't work, probably for several reasons, one of them is I can't figure out the syntax or where it belongs (maybe it can be combined with something earlier) I get the error that it can only be used in LINQ to entities. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
this is what works for the last part

```
                var grouped = from e in ac
                              group e by new
                              {
                                  e.date_opened.Date,
                                  e.attending
                              } into g
                              orderby g.Key.Date
                              select new
                              {
                                  g.Key.Date,
                                  g.Key.attending,
                                  total = g.Count(),
                                  tdenovo = g.Sum(x => x.denovo),
                                  txr = g.Sum(x => x.xr),
                                  tct = g.Sum(x => x.ct),
                                  tus = g.Sum(x => x.us),
                                  tmr = g.Sum(x => x.mr),
                                  tother = g.Sum(x => x.other)
                              };
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `CountModel()` from the line `var mathQuery = ac.GroupBy(u => new CountModel()` so the grouping is by an anonymous type, which can be converted to SQL.

Comment: I'm getting error "'This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities."

Answer (score 0):

The List "ac" is not an Entity object so the call to DbFunctions is probably causing the issue.

Try this if the date is nullable:

```
tdate = u.date_opened.HasValue ? u.date_opened.Value.Date : null,
```

or this:

```
tdate = u.date_opened.Date,
```

Comment: this worked!  Thank you!  Now I am trying to figure out how to make it group by 7 day blocks instead